# Spring Security ignore path filter still executed when Authorization header present

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a fully working spring security process set up with some paths requiring authentication (via a token) and others I want to keep open and accessible without token. The issue I am running into is that when a request comes in to one of those open paths without the `Authorization` header, then the filters are ignored and the proper response is generated. However, when the `Authorization` header is present, even though on the ignored path, the request goes through the entire security filter chain when the ideal procedure would be to entirely skip the filter chain.

Below is my configuration.

```java
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers(DEFAULT_IGNORE_REQUESTS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        authenticationTokenHeaderFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/example/**")
                    .authenticated()
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler((request, response, accessDeniedException) -> {
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, accessDeniedException.getMessage());
                })
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpAuthenticationEntryPoint())
            .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
                .cors()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .addFilter(authenticationTokenHeaderFilter)
                .addFilterBefore(new ExceptionTranslationFilter(
                                new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint()),
                        authenticationTokenHeaderFilter.getClass()
                );
    }
```

```
public class AuthenticationTokenHeaderFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {
    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        return httpServletRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        return "N/A";
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

I have additionally tried putting the ignored paths to the `HttpSecurity` with `permitAll()` with no success.

#### Clarification

```java
String[] DEFAULT_IGNORE_REQUESTS = new String[]{ "/actuator" };
```

In what is described above, any requests going to `/example/**` should go through the security chain and through my filter to make sure the user is authenticated. Any requests going to `/actuator` should not go through the security filter chain. The `/example/**` works correctly and as expected. The `/actuator` however does not.

When I make a request **without** the `Authorization` header, the security chain is not invoked.
When I make a request **with** the `Authorization` header present, the security chain is invoked and the `Authorization` value (token) is verified. In the event that the token is invalid, a custom exception gets thrown inside the filter. Even though the error gets thrown, I get the expected response from `/actuator` with a 200. The thrown error in this case however gets logged and a stack trace gets generated, which I do not want as it's not an error in that case.

Comment: Could you add the source code for the authenticationTokenHeaderFilter?

Comment: @NatFar Added to original post. The `AuthenticationManager` then manages verifying that the `Authorization` token is correct and may throw errors that then get handled by me. My whole problem here is that I only want those errors to be thrown when I am attempting to access a path that is secured. I can build a messy workaround to make it work by checking if path is valid inside the `AuthenticationManager`, but I'd imagine there's a way to make it work by having Spring handle it.

Comment: @NTL What URL do you call? What is the value of `DEFAULT_IGNORE_REQUESTS`?

Comment: You say that the filter chain is invoked if the Authorization header is on an "ignored path" - like one that matches DEFAULT_IGNORE_REQUESTS or simply another path for which the user doesn't have to be authenticated?

Comment: @NatFar sorry I was away for the weekend. Updated the original post under the `Clarification` heading.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? And how do you obtain the AuthenticationTokenHeaderFilter in your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter?

Comment: @NatFar Yes I am using Spring Boot. The AuthenticationTokenHeaderFilter gets instantiated in a `@Bean` and then gets accessed via `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Spring Boot, any `@Bean` of type `Filter` gets added as a servlet filter. What's most likely happening is that your filter is being added as a filter entirely separate from the filter chain.

Instead of declaring your filter as a `@Bean`, you could initialize `AuthenticationTokenHeaderFilter` in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and set the `AuthenticationManager` directly (which you already do anyways). So you can remove the `@Autowired` annotation in the filter.